# XML Help required

Tags: xml, xslt

All

I have an XML of following format

```
 <a>
<a1 id="1"/>
<a1 id="2"/>
<a1 id="3"/>
<a1 id="4"/>
<a1 id="5"/>
</a>
```

Now, USING XSLT I want to delete first 2 nodes (based on their positions) and make XML again. So the output of above should be following XML:

```
<a>

    <a1 id="3"/>
    <a1 id="4"/>
    <a1 id="5"/>
    </a>
```

Code I have Used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />
  <xsl:template match="a1">
  &lt;a1&gt;
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>

    </xsl:copy>
&lt;/a1&gt;
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="a1[position()&lt;2]"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But The output I am getting is

```
<a1> 2 </a1>
  <a1> 3 </a1>
  <a1> 4 </a1>
  <a1> 5 </a1>
```

Comment: You need to say what you are doing. Are you writing code? What language? Include the code in your question.

Comment: I want to do it through XSLT Code

Comment: Edited the question, hope that helps

Comment: You will always get better answers if you first supply us with what you have tried and why it is not working. Most people here will not do your work for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use `fn:position()` when processing your child elements of `<a>`

> fn:position() : Returns the index position of the node that is  currently being processed
>
> Example: //book[position()<=3] Result: Selects the first three book
> elements

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: So basically I am wring this code:

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />
  <xsl:template match="a1">
  &lt;a1&gt;
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
     
    </xsl:copy>
&lt;/a1&gt;
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="a1[position()&lt;2]"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

but the expected output was:
<a>
  <a1> 2 </a1>
  <a1> 3 </a1>
  <a1> 4 </a1>
  <a1> 5 </a1>
</a>

How to get 'a' parent node?

Comment: The output which I am getting is 
  <a1> 2 </a1>
  <a1> 3 </a1>
  <a1> 4 </a1>
  <a1> 5 </a1>

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called the identity template to accomplish this very easily. That would be the first template in my example. All that says is process every attribute and node. After that all you have to do is not process any `a1` node with a position less than 3 by using a blank template.

So using this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a1[position()&lt;3]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On this XML

```
<a>
  <a1 id="1"/>
  <a1 id="2"/>
  <a1 id="3"/>
  <a1 id="4"/>
  <a1 id="5"/>
</a>
```

Produces this output

```
<a>


  <a1 id="3"/>
  <a1 id="4"/>
  <a1 id="5"/>
</a>
```